# How to remove those little tick bars on the axis line?

Tags: pgfplots

the tick bars are there, like forever....
How can I remove those little bars?
[image]

Comment: With no information about a code of this picture, we can probably suggest only an eraser.

Comment: This is your fourth question on this site, but you are still reluctant to provide us with an MWE, even when @marmot has asked you to in your very first post. Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Those little bars are called Ticks. Search the pgfplots manual for ticks options.

And try putting these commands inside the options of your axis environment. Something like

```
\begin{axis}[
xtick =\empty, 
ytick =\empty
]
```

Share the code here if this doesn't help you.

Comment: +1 Please consider adding the code from my answer such that I can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the code of my previous answer I confirm the statement by Orides Wladislau Golyjeswski *if* you add this option to the second axis. Of course, Orides Wladislau Golyjeswski can hardly be more specific because you did not provide an MWE. I will be happy to remove my answer if Orides Wladislau Golyjeswski adds the code (or some modification thereof) to his.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
%    width=0.45\textwidth,
%    height=0.3\textheight,
   symbolic x coords={2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017},
   enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.05},
   }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xtick pos=left,
   axis y line*=left,
   ybar,
   bar width=0.2cm,
    ymin=0, ymax=50,
   ytick={0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
   yticklabels={0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
   ylabel style={align=center},
   ylabel={Number of publication containing the keywords \\ ``A+B'},
   xticklabel style={
      inner sep=0pt,
      anchor=north east,
      rotate=60
      },
   ]
   \addplot[ybar legend,fill=gray,draw=gray] coordinates {
     (2006,1) (2007,8) (2008,6) (2009,7) (2010,11) (2011,9) (2012,30) (2013,25) (2014,18) (2015,37) (2016,46) (2017,0)
     };
     \end{axis}


\begin{axis}[
   axis y line*=right,
   xticklabels={},
   ymin=700, ymax=1200,
   ytick={700,800,900,1000,1100,1200},
   ylabel style={align=center,rotate=180,red},
   ylabel={Number of publication containing the keywords \\ ``C+D''},
   xtick=\empty
   ]
    \addplot[thick,draw=red] plot coordinates{
      (2006,752) (2007,888) (2008,908) (2009,920) (2010,1010) (2011,1003) (2012,1081) (2013,1082) (2014,1075) (2015,1092) (2016,1100) (2017,0)
      };
      \coordinate (X) at (axis cs:2013,1082);     
   \end{axis}
   \draw[thick,red,-latex] (X) |- ++(0.5,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]